# Can you insert a custom value in an Auto-incrementing field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

The column auto-increments. User wants to insert a row with a specific number (I've confirmed it doesn't already exist in the column). In SQL Server I'd do a quick `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` and insert statement. Is there a way to this for Microsoft Access or are they just out of luck.

Comment: Can run an INSERT action SQL. But then need to Compact & Repair to reset the autonumber seed.

Comment: Just say no. It's an identity column, the values in it are by definition meaningless, it's just a way to get a unique value on a row.

Comment: @June7 this worked, if you make it a full answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can run an INSERT action SQL.

But then need to Compact & Repair to reset the autonumber seed. Or, per @4dmonster comment, run another INSERT with the maximum autonumber value already in database. As long as the autonumber is set for unique index, the insert will fail but sequence will be fixed and normal data entry will generate next number. I tested and it worked.

I can only guess this autonumber is used as a sequential number that must be accounted for, as in a license number series. Otherwise, sequence gaps should not be a concern and can be ignored.

Comment: instead of Compact & Repair(if there is unique index at auto-increments field) you can run SQL to insert empty row with maximum value, query will fail but sequence will be fixed, and next generated value will be next number.

Answer (score 0):

NotAn answer, but a workaround.  Don't make the column autoincrement, but set the default value to max current values plus one.  The defualt will,  in effect, step up by one, but the user can pick a different value.  Has not been tested on very large tables.

Comment: Does have risk of multiple users generating same value. If use this, immediately commit record to table.